# Detach controls from video tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I would like to detach controls from the video tag, not hide them, just detach them from the video, is anyone having any solution ?

Comment: There may be some browser specific pseudo-selectors to achieve this with CSS, but it won't work the same for every browsers, and being out of official specifications, their behavior may change any time, i.e just do yours, there are many examples on how to build simple to advanced controls on the web.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control how the browser's native video controls are rendered beyond "they are" and "they are not".

If you want to change their position or appearance then you need to turn off the native controls and render your own, JavaScript-powered, ones.